# Find difference of two large files

Tags: java, diff

I want to compute the file difference. And it is possible that files can be very large, e.g. 25 MB.

My idea is to compute the files by parts, e.g. first comparing the first 1000 bytes, and then second 1000 bytes, and so on.

Does Java-Diff-Utils (or others) support compute difference by parts, which means it needs to store the state and not treat the second 1000 bytes as a new file?

How can I make it also store the line number?
Thx!

Edit:
The file is txt file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give more information. For example, what kind of file you want to compare, is there time constraint, whether you encountered a problem using Java-Diff-Utils. In absence of that, following is just a thought:

If you look at professional diff tools, I usually use winmerge (https://winmerge.org), they have different ways to treat different *types* of files. So, a XML or CSV or json with different order of tags is still file with same *information*. If you want to compare to non-structured files, for example .txt, it would not matter if java-diff-utils treats chunks as same file or not. Otherwise, you will *have to* worry about it.

Based on their help page and examples (https://github.com/java-diff-utils/java-diff-utils/wiki/Examples) it seems two blocks are essentially two files. But even if it is so, you should be able to override that behaviour (Seeing as it is open source).